# Is there a way to exclude specific class in a package when gluing a package in cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber

Hi I want to glue the package

com.jayanath.test.bdt.multiPos but need to exclude class
com.jayanath.test.bdt.multiPos.SetupMultiPos.java

Is there a way to do that
What I did was

> @Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-htmlreport",
>           "json-pretty:target/cucumber-report.json"},
>           glue = {"com.jayanath.test.bdt.multiPos","~com.jayanath.test.bdt.multiPos.SetupMultiPos"},
>           tags = {"@OLO"})

Based on my knowledge about tags. But it did not work.

Comment: Why don't you put them into a separate package?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Bala.  But this is only a one place where I need to do the exclusion. In our framework we have step definitions under different packages and we re use them to avoid duplication. Some  has cucumber.Before methods which runs whenever step definition in same class is referred. I want to exclude classes that have before methods. Refactoring by moving to another package is cannot be done.